# Changing background colour of specific select2 through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

In a web form, I'm using two select2 control at two panel each.

I wish to change only one of the select2's background colour when it hit certain condition through javascript else it will remain its original colour.

How can I accomplish that?

I am at the stage where the css code below I found is able to modify the select2 to the result I want.

```
       .select2-container .select2-selection{
        background: yellow;
        }
```

Any help is much appreciated.

**Edited:**

Adding some part of my code:

*CSS*

```
    .select2-container {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        float: left;
        margin-bottom: 0;
        display: table;
        table-layout: fixed;
        font-size: smaller;
    }
```

*Markup*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <table>
           <tr>
                 <td>
                     <select id="ddl_Select2ONE" runat="server" class="form-control select"></select>
                 </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <table>
           <tr>
                 <td>
                     <select id="ddl_Select2TWO" runat="server" class="form-control select"></select>
                 </td>
           </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Javascript*

```
pageLoad(){
  configureSelect2()
}

configureSelect2(){
    if(hf_value.value == "1"){
        //Change only ddl_Select2ONE to yellow background
    }
    else{
        //Change only ddl_Select2ONE to original background
    }
}
```

Then I will perform some checking on javascript's pageload when it check a hidden field value for conditional enable.

Comment: post your html code also

Comment: If the CDs is already working then $('.select2-container .select2-selection').css({backgroundColor: 'yellow'});

Comment: @prasad I have added some rewrite of my code to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved and solution provided here :**

What I need was the "!important" in css class and finding the span I need to add the css class to.

*CSS*

```
    .yellowBackground{
        background: yellow !important;
    }
```

*javascript*

```
function pageLoad(){
  configureSelect2()
}

function configureSelect2(){

        td_Name = document.getElementById("<%=td_Name.ClientID %>");
        if (hf_Value.value == "1") {
            ($(td_Name).find('span')).addClass('yellowBackground');
        }
        else {
            ($(td_Name).find('span')).removeClass('yellowBackground');
        }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:**

```
document.getElementById('idOfElement').classList.add('select2-container')`;
```

**Or using jquery:**

```
$("#idOfElement").addClass("select2-container");
$("#idOfElement").addClass("select2-selection");
```

Comment: You mean add the cssClass I wrote in my question? If I wrote it on css script it will run the script first which make all my select2 yellow before any condition checking happen

Answer (score 0):

Ok your javascript should look something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#ddl_Select2ONE').style.background = "Yellow";
```

And in your else clause:

```
document.querySelector('#ddl_Select2TWO').style.background = "Yellow";
```

Comment: I have added my html code (just rewrite of my own code as it is very large code) to my question

Comment: Not working as *document.querySelector('#ddl_Select2ONE').style.background = "Yellow";* return error message *Cannot read property 'style' of null*

Comment: document.querySelector('#ddl_Select2ONE').style.background = 'yellow'

works for me with your html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> 1. function declaration syntax was wrong.
> 2. use with [**`classList`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp) function

```
//add in your js

        function pageLoad() {
          configureSelect2()
        }

        function configureSelect2() {
          if (hf_value.value == "1") {
        document.getElementById("ddl_Select2ONE").classList.add("yellow");
          } else {
           document.getElementById("ddl_Select2ONE").classList.remove("yellow");
          }
        }




 //add in your css
        .yellow{
        background-color:yellow !important;
        }
```

Comment: Not working as colour did not change even if I removed the condition. Shouldn't it modify the *.select2-container .select2-selection* background colour instead of adding new class?

Comment: but your mention with in a question only `ddl_Select2ONE` background color  was change ..@JamesYTL can you clarify more bit

Comment: my bad. Modifying select2-container .select2-selection is not the right way. i have posted the method I used to make only one select2's background colour change.